# DNS works, ping/wget/ntp/etc does not. (linux)

Tags: linux, dns, ping, arch-linux

I am trying to do a netinstall of archlinux (done that quite a few times before) but i cant get the internet connection to work on my machine. i used the same settings of the previous (working!) ubuntu and windows 7 installation. hostnames get resolved proberly by the dns server but ping, traceroute, wget, curl, ntp and everything else does not work.

the only information i foound is this from 2011: [Internet over Ethernet: DNS works, ping doesn't (Windows works, Linux doesn't)](https://superuser.com/questions/323804/internet-over-ethernet-dns-works-ping-doesnt-windows-works-linux-doesnt)

i think the solution would be to add the computer to a windows workgroup (dont ask me why, i just faintly remember that this fixed that problem two years ago) but i dont know how to add the live installation system to one.

ifconfig eth0:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:08:C7:0D:42:93
inet addr:10.1.13.8 Bcast:10.255.255.255 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: fe80::208:c7ff:fe0d:4293/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets: 1229 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:155445 (151.8Kb) TX bytes:166845 (162.9 Kb)
Interrupt:10 Base address:0xb800
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 10.1.10.10
```

route:

```
Destination    Gateway    Genmask    Flags    Metric    Ref    Use    Iface
default    10.1.10.10    0.0.0.0    UG    0    0    0    eth0
10.0.0.0    *    255.0.0.0    U    0    0    0    eth0
```

wget google.com:

```
Resolving google.com... 173.194.70.139, 173.194.70.100, 173.194.70.101, ...
Connecting to google.com|173.194.70.139|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

traceroute google.com:

```
traceroute: Warning: google.com has multiple addresses; using 173.194.70.100
traceroute to google.com (173.194.70.100), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
etc...
```

I just installed the base system of archlinux using a core installer. i configured the netwerk the same way i did on the installer-livesystem and as it is configured on windows 7 and was before on ubuntu and i still have the same problem :(

Comment: Have you tried pinging ip-addresses? Does your iSP require you to login to use internet, i.e pppoe? If so, only having dns makes sense until you provide credentials.

Comment: sadly this also does not work :(

Comment: Sounds like you didn't set the default gateway or set the default gateway incorrectly.

Comment: default gw is 10.1.10.10 which also works on win7 and ubuntu on the same machine and every other machine in the office :/

Comment: Does the default gw know how to contact the 10.1.13.X segment?

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this happen would be as follows:

- Have a DNS server on your LAN, for example a router that acts as a DNS forwarder.
- Correctly configure `/etc/resolv.conf`
- Make a mistake when manually configuring the default gateway in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

For a more accurate answer, it would help if you updated your question with

- some sanitised information about your configuration, location of DNS server, routers.
- actual error messages for whatever "does not work".

Comment: DNS Server & Gateway is 10.1.10.10 (i also added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS Servers. My IP Address is 10.1.13.8 and netmask is 255.0.0.0

Comment: I do see 10.1.10.10 as default route (both destination 0.0.0.0 and flags UG)

Comment: This makes sense.  Local traffic works (DNS server 10.1.10.10). Remote doesn't.

Comment: @yaccin: Traceroute shows your default gateway not responding. I'd suspect some firewall rules in the router may be causing problems.